# Relational algebra selection operator

Tags: database, relational-algebra

Suppose if there's a database schema as follows:

employee(id, name, address)

Suppose if we have to find employees whose name starts with 'A', how to write a relational algebra for such query?

Most of the readings only deal with exact matching such as 'name="Adams"' but don't explain about pattern matching in relational algebra. Can't we write 'name="A*"' or 'name="A%"' in relational algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the LIKE operator:

```
select_{name like 'A%'}
```

Comment: Ron, thank you! 

I also stumbled into http://www.cs.duke.edu/~junyang/ra/ and while using that tool, I used the query like you suggested and it worked. 

For other who are willing to learn RA, this tool might be very helpful. You need to have JRE or JAVA installed to run the program.

Comment: I see you are new to SO,  -it is customary to reward correct answers.